# Как подправить вид обычного селекта?

Tags: css3, html, html5, css

Здравствуйте.
Есть простой элемент `SELECT`. Он выглядит так:

[image: простой селект]

Как убрать значек справа так, чтобы он, например, выглядел так:

[image: Нужный селект]

**PS**:
Этот *селект* должен всегда оставаться *селектом*. Т.е. при помощи библиотек и `JS`, чтобы его не переделывать в, например, `<UL> <LI> ... ... ...` и тому подобное.
И не используя библиотеки, если для стилизации нужен `JS`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Очень просто стилизировать селект без создания монструозной хтмл структуры, которая имитирует поведения элемента. Для этого используют фичу/баг с прозрачностью тега селект, а именно если задать opacity:0 селеку, то по клику на него options будут показываться нормально без прозрачности. Поэтому надо сделать див со стилями как вам надо, а поверх него наложить селект с абсолютным позиционированием и нулевой прозрачностью, работать будет как обчный селект без проблем.

Но вот чтобы выбранное значение изменялось в диве в зависимости от выбранного знчения в селекте, нужно написать простенький скрипт, который бы это значение считывал и записывал в див на onchange.

P.S. А зачем так издеваться над пользователями?

Comment: Так вобщем:

 <div id="container">
  <input type="text" name="pseudoSelect" id="pseudo-select" value="1"/>
  <select id="select" onchange="pseudoSelect.value=this.value">
   <option>1</option>
   <option>2</option>
   <option>3</option>
  </select>
 </div>

 <style>
  #container {position:relative}
  #pseudo-select,#select {position:absolute;top:0;left:0}
  #pseudo-select {width:30px}
  #select {z-index:1;opacity:0;width:50px}
 </style>

Comment: ну да так, только объедините цсс для #select в один и добавьте document.getElementById('pseudoSelect').value и вам надо не значение селекта а текст внутри options

Comment: @makregistr , вы просто молодец! Это даже больше, чем мне надо! Я и не думал, что, если `select` будет невидимым, то все равно он будет работать как надо. Спасибо вам.  
И по поводу издевательства, так тут совсем нет его. Мне необходимо было изменить вид селекта, но не менять сам тэг.